# Enthought Canopy 1.0 missing Python.h and other includes

Tags: python-2.7, build, enthought, setup.py, canopy

I installed the Canopy distribution from Enthought for Mac OSX 64 bit and the include/python-2.7 folder is missing.

I couldn't find a package that includes this, has anyone had this problem and a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Canopy uses a backport of [`venv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/venv) to provide the Python that gets exposed to users. `venv` does not copy the include directories, but `distutils` will find and use the include directory from the parent distribution, for example, modulo specific version numbers, it will probably look like this:

`/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7/`

If you try compiling a simple extension module, it should work. Please give it a try and let us know if a simple extension module does not work.